# how to put a counter in the Group By using SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 column below with corresponding data:

```
Name    Category
A       SL
B       SL
C       SL
A       SL
A       SL
C       SL
```

now in my script, i group them in Category to know the counter on how many times they occurred:

```
select Name, count(*) from Customer
group by Category
```

but i want to count on how many times they occur in the query like below:

```
Customer    Number#
A           1 (means its the first time it occurs)
A           2 (means its the second time it occurs)
A           3 (means its the third time it occurs)
```

....so on

```
B           1 (means its the first time it occurs)
C           1 (means its the first time it occurs)
C           2 (means its the second time it occurs)
```

sorry for confusion, hope its clear for everyone.

Thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Following Query:-

```
SELECT name + '-' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY id) AS VARCHAR(24))
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: My Pleasure. but still -1

Comment: sorry, i can't vote because it needs 15 reputation.